# IE Hover Issue with an Image Overlay

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover, overlay, opacity

I have an image and an overlay within an image wrapper. Hovering over the wrapper causes the overlay to go from transparency 0 to 0.8. It works in all browsers but IE. I believe I am using the proper IE filter for opacity. Please take a look at the code:

HTML

```
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img class="profile" src="images/z.jpg">
    <a href="team-employee-z.html" class="img-overlay team"> </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img-wrap {
    margin-right: 3px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
}

.img-overlay {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

.img-overlay.team {
    top: 0;
}

.img-wrap:hover .img-overlay {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0.80;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 80);
    transition: opacity 0.25s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s;
}
```

Comment: IE has many versions - best to specify the ones you care about.

Comment: Maybe you must reset the proper filter  in `.img-wrap:hover`. Try:  `-ms-filter: "";`

Answer (score 0):

-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

this filter should work for ie 7-8

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is in all IE versions (including 9/10)

Comment: u can still try this filter, since you are going to need it anyway. You can try removing all the extra filter lines and get the basic to work.